# How to edit tags in AAC files?

Tags: software-recommendation, aac

In the old days, there used to be [an EasyTag extension](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=949018) specifically for this purpose. Today there does not seem to be one and EasyTag does not list AAC files in its GUI. Rythmbox issues an error editing AAC files.

Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to rename you files from *.aac to *.m4a.

Then EasyTag will be able to see the files and edit the tags normally, that's what I just did.

If you really want to keep the file extension, you can always rename them back to *.aac afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [EasyTAG](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG) harder, as its webpage says:

> EasyTAG is a simple application for viewing and editing tags in audio files. It supports MP3, MP2, MP4/**AAC**, FLAC, Ogg Opus, Ogg Speex, Ogg Vorbis, MusePack, Monkey's Audio, and WavPack files

Answer (score 2):

Trusty Tahr 14.04 ships with EasyTag 2.1.10 and this release incorporates an important change dealing with m4a/aac tagging. Taken from the [Ubuntu Changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/e/easytag/easytag_2.1.10-1ubuntu1/changelog):

> - Switch to TagLib for MP4 tag editing and drop libmp4v2 support

This change was introduced for Easytag 2.1.8-1 and gets around the licensing issues which made it difficult for Debian / Ubuntu to have a version of Easytag in the repository that could edit aac files.

So from Trusty Tahr onward there is no need for installing extensions, recompiling, adding PPAs, searching for other applications; to edit the metadata in m4a / aac files you simply need:

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```

Happy tagging :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an AAC file at hand, but I believe that kid3 does it.
Install it using the software center or get the latest version here: http://kid3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Kid3 is a very nice programme, faster and with a better interface than EasyTag. It is able to play and edit AAC files (wich EasyTag can not). However, the tags it creates are not recognised by any of the media players I use: Rhythmbox, VLC, Totem, etc.